# Global access to the database does not work

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I did the WebAPI and Angular collaboration here - https://angular.io/tutorial
but they fill the heroes themselves there. And I need to get the names from my already created database. The request in WebAPI works. when i go to api / theater via webapi project i am output correctly.

So I need your advice. So how did I make it impossible to work with global databases?

If I do the following in the theater.service files -

```
     export class TheatresService {
  private theatreUrl = 'api/Theatre';
```

then nothing will work

and if I put it that way -

```
     export class TheatresService {
  private theatreUrl = 'api/theatres';
```

which I tossed in the file, it will be displayed correctly.

The file with theatres
in-memory-data-service.ts

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Theatre } from './theatres.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class InMemoryDataServiceTheatre implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    const theatres = [
      { id: 11, name: 'theatre' },
      { id: 12, name: 'opera'},
      { id: 13, name: 'operatta' },
    ];
    return {theatres};
  }
}
```

And app.module.ts

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
   .......
  ],
  imports: [
    ........
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataServiceTheatre, {dataEncapsulation: false}
    )
  ],
  providers: [TheatresService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Tell me what is wrong. or drop the link showing how to work with the internal database

UPD
    My model

```
     namespace TicketSalePoint.Data.Models
{
    [Table("Theatres")]
    public class Theatre
    {
        public Theatre() { }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegistrationDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Show> Shows { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My controller with webAPI

```
    namespace TicketSalePointWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class TheatreController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetNames()
        {
            using (var dataBaseContext = new DataBaseContext())
            {
                dataBaseContext.Database.Connection.Open();
                var query = from theatre in dataBaseContext.Theatres
                            select new { theatre.Id, theatre.Name };

                return Ok(await query.ToListAsync());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I see error:

```
{body: {…}, url: "api/Theatre", headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found"}
body: {error: "Collection 'Theatre' not found"}
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
url: "api/Theatre"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: @SiddAjmera I basically don't care whether in InMemoryDataServiceTheatre or anywhere. but I want the data to be read from my existing database
 I did UPD and filled in my code and I saw an error in the sender

Comment: @SiddAjmera 
Can you force a tutorial or an example how to do it? and then I just killed it on google and didn't understand how to do it. thanks

Comment: @SiddAjmera That is, can InMemoryDataServiceTheaters be deleted? it doesn't suit me .... ok i will delete

Comment: @SiddAjmera I found this tutorial- https://restfulapi.net/rest-api-design-tutorial-with-example/    but I did not understand how it worked in my case

Comment: @SiddAjmera 
How do I deploy?

Comment: I'm not really an expert in WebAPIs and stuff. You might want to do a Google search about it.